# Why is Dispatcher launching unnecessary events on Flux?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux

I have a React/Flux app with a view of following components:

- header.js
- subnav-area.js
- feed-area.js

I also have corresponding stores:

- navbar-store.js (header)
- subnav-store.js
- feed-store.js

...and actions:

- navbar-actions.js (header)
- subnav-actions.js
- feed-actions.js

When pressing a button on subnav, both the feed and the subnav should be updated, setting right kind of feed and highlighting the active subnav element. I am succesful with this goal, but I am also launching an onChange event multiple times, also with header.js component, even though it should not be affected with the action.

In actions I am calling dispatcher like this:

```
AppDispathcer.handleViewAction({

  actionType: AppConstants.SUBNAV_SET_ACTIVE,
  _id: subnavItemId
})
```

...depending on the purpose, of course. My dispatcher looks like this:

handleViewAction: function(action) {

this.dispatch({
    source: 'VIEW_ACTION',
    action: action
  })
}

In stores I have something like this for handling the dispatcher:

```
dispatcherIndex: AppDispatcher.register(function(payload) {

  var action = payload.action;

  switch(action.actionType) {

    case AppConstants.FILTER_SET_CAT:

        FeedStore.selectVisibleFeedItems();
      break;

    case AppConstants.FEED_SHOW_MORE:

        FeedStore.showMoreItems(filterCatName);
      break;
  }

  FeedStore.emitChange();

  return true;
})
```

All the components have following functions (but with different listener names):

```
  componentWillMount:function(){

    FeedStore.addFeedListener(this._onChange, 'feed-area.js');
  },

  componentWillUnmount:function() {

    FeedStore.removeFeedListener(this._onChange)
  },

  _onChange: function(){

    this.setState(getVisibleFeedItems())
  },
```

Now when the desired action happens, _onChange is launched on all: header, subnav-area and feed-area components.

Where do I start looking for the bug? I don't fully understand how the dispatcher works, should I somehow separate the functions for handling the view? I thought Flux somehow listens the stores and updates views according to it, now it seems it is listening something else and I don't really understand what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll begin describing an example of the general idea and then go on how you could debug things.

Let's say i have a Shopping Cart and a Item `Component`.

Whenever an `add` event is fired from the `Item` component it should trigger an `Action` which, lets say, make an AJAX request to your server and then dispatch an event called `CART_ITEM_ADDED`(In your case i guess you would do `Dispatcher.handleViewAction('CART_ITEM_ADDED')`. The dispatcher would tell it's subscribers that an event was received and each subscriber would see if it's interested in that event. The subscriber(s) that are interested in the `CART_ITEM_ADDED` event could then update the `CartStore` and tell it to refetch the cart from the server. Once done the store would fire an event saying no more than "OK. I've changed" and then it would be the responsibility of each view that is subscribing to `CartStore` to refetch the information they need from the CartStore.

On to debugging:

In my dispatchers, when running debug mode, i always print what events are being dispatched. So in your `handleViewAction` you could do a `console.log('[DISPATCH]', action);` which would give you a clear overview of which events are being dispatched and in what order.

You could do the same thing when your stores emit a change event. Log it and you'll know whats happened.

It's very hard for me to tell you the exact problem without more to go on but normally it's very easy to confuse and mix the constants for your dispatcher callback & actioncreators. Maybe you are listening for the wrong events in the wrong places somewhere?

Also i see you're doing something like

```
FeedStore.addFeedListener(this._onChange, 'feed-area.js');
```

Is there any reason why you don't use a generic `addEventListener`?

All you should tell the store is "Hey! Run this function whenever something has happened, ok?" by doing `FeedStore.addEventListener(this._onChange);`

This became a longer answer than i expected, and i hope it helps, if not then please feel free to ask!

Comment: I hacked together this small pseudo code quick. Maybe it helps a bit to understand the concept: http://pastebin.com/5Zpi9zRJ

Comment: Awesome stuff! "The dispatcher would tell it's subscribers that an event was received and each subscriber would see if it's interested in that event." This clarifies the concept a lot to me.

I am afraid this comment field is not long enough to explain why I use different listener names. But generally when I had the same listener names in every stores they got mixed (or actually replaced) in event emitter. Apparently my stores extend the EventEmitter. I don't know if that is a right approach, copied it from some tutorial.

Comment: Ok, the problem was that I was launching FeedStore.emitChange(); every time there was dispatcher event. I think I am | | <-- that close to understand what is going on. Because all the stores are listening to the same dispatcher (there is supposed to be only one?) and I wasn't "asking if they are interested" in the event, I was unpurposefully launching the emitChange? So, in other words, does the emitChange launch onChange event on all of the stores listening the dispatcher?

Comment: @JaakkoKarhu: I'm not following a 100% but i think i get the point. You should only launch `FeedStore.emitChange();` when something actually changed in FeedStore. Your dispatcher callback could look like this: http://pastebin.com/RMSEphNY

I'll try to help until you get it right so just keep coming with feedback & we'll solve this!

Comment: @JaakkoKarhu: I started off some existing jsfiddle and rewrote it so you can see the basic concept in action: http://jsfiddle.net/rhs1um2c/2/ Hope it helps!

Comment: I am not surprised its hard to follow, I was writing very tired yesterday. However, your fiddles and codes help a lot thank you for your effort! I copied your fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/jaakkokarhu/8kLod1xa/2/ and commented with prefix JK for further discussion. I also added one of my stores in pastebin: http://pastebin.com/s3mwr6Zb with few comments about event listeners and store objects. I hope I've been able to put my questions clearly enough.

Comment: Replies here: http://jsfiddle.net/8kLod1xa/4/

The dispatcher callbacks determine what to do with events sent through the dispatcher. If it's interested in something it will update the store with data.
Once something changes in the store that store should emit a change event(`.emitChange()`) to notify the components.

So a `Store` should only do a `.emitChange()` if it has been updated with new data. Then the components listening to that store will know that they should call something like `FeedStore.getFeed()`

I'm not sure my comments are enough. But keep asking and i'll try to help!

Comment: Here are some replies to your pastebin: http://pastebin.com/x0VBwFiJ

It explains why addChangeListener didn't work for you!

Comment: Ok, its working now and the unnecessary events launching is gone. I don't fully understand the concept of BaseStore and what happens when I stuff my other stores there. I also realised that even tho we were talking about putting registers to separate file, wouldn't that actually mean possibility to call undeclared functions in stores. Now when they come with stores they are related to, that kind of an mistakes are impossible or at least easier to avoid, correct?

Comment: Great to hear! Well, no, because you'd have to require the store and use it just as you would normally. I suggest you take a look at facebooks flux BaseStore(it should be identical to the one i showed you) and maybe look more into how assign works! The general idea is that you create a generic store which all other stores inherit so you don't have to make addChange../removeChange../emit functions for every store manually.